# Automatic weight paint of solid mesh (with some thickness)

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing, rigging, weight-painting

How can I properly weight paint a mesh that has a thickness to it?

I created a jacket and then added and applied a solidify modifier to give it some thickness. When I parent the jacket to my rig with automatic weights, the mesh's two sides have varying amounts of weight paint.

Ideally, both sides of the jacket should be equivalent.

In the example screenshot, you can see how the inside of the sleeve is light blue whereas the outside faces are red.

When I pose the model in certain positions, the inner faces poke out of the out faces.

Is there an automatic way of correcting this? The only manual method that I know of is manually repainting the weights with "front faces only" disabled.

[image: Screen Shot 2020-09-27 at 10.27.11 AM|530x500]

Here, the dark orange texture on the side is actually the inner faces poking through. The entire jacket should be yellow on the outside (except for the blue accents on the sleeves).

[image: Screen Shot 2020-09-27 at 10.32.47 AM|530x500]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment, to paint through you need to go in the brush settings and disable the *Front Faces Only* and the *Front-face Falloff* options, and enable *Projected*. Don't ask me what are the purposes of all these options  ;)   It's a bit tedious in my opinion, they should create one unique option to paint through:

[image]